# Debian; Personal Data and Privacy

Tags: debian

**1** I learned that windows collects some data from users. And actually the question i wanted to ask came out. Does Debian collect personal data of its users?

**2** I downloaded some test versions of Debian. Could they be collecting information from us to find bugs in these versions?

**3** And with all this; Can I securely login to my accounts using debian?

By the way, debian bullseye is excellent. I downloaded it yesterday, simple stylish and elegant.

Comment: Debian privacy policy is is fully documented at https://www.debian.org/legal/privacy

Comment: Actually, that's the first link I looked. But this part confused me: `Various other aspects of interacting with the Debian Project will, however, involve the collection of personal information. This is primarily in the form of names and email addresses in emails received by the project; all Debian mailing lists are publicly archived, as are all interactions with the bug tracking system` @steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian does not collect personal information from its users by default.

When you install, you are given an opportunity to participate in the Popularity Contest, which sends anonymized data on which packages are in use so that Debian can structure its CDs with the most popular packages first.  However, you are not obligated to participate, and Debian doesn't send usage data otherwise.

Of course, if you are making a network connections to other machines, those machines will be able to see that you are connecting and what data they're serving you.  Debian tries hard to ensure that software it ships doesn't make non-essential connections to upstream that would expose users' privacy without their knowledge, but it may not have caught every instance.

The message you saw in the privacy policy basically says that if you use mailing lists, source code servers, or bug tracking systems operated by the project that that information is public and can be seen by everyone.  That is expected of an open source project like Debian.  If you wish to participate pseudonymously, you generally may do so.

Your files, user information, and other contents of your computer are not sent to Debian unless you specifically choose to send them (e.g., as an attachment to a bug report).

Debian ships standard web browsers, such as Firefox and Chromium (the open source version of Chrome), so you can securely log into most websites with it.  Similarly, it ships a variety of mail clients which you can securely use for email, and so on.  Whether it will meet all of your needs depends on what those needs are.  However, many people, myself included, do use it as a daily driver and it is of course very capable in a variety of areas.